# Drawing on Android canvas

Tags: java, android

I want to write a function drawCircle with 2 parameters x,y position. Whenever i touch on the screen, i will get x,y position and pass to the drawCircle function and draw a circle on the screen.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private canvasview cv1;
private double tx,ty;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    cv1=new canvasview(this);

    setContentView(cv1);
    eventtouch();
}

public double gettx()
{
    return tx;
}
public double getty()
{
    return ty;
}
protected void eventtouch()
{

    cv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            tx=motionEvent.getX();
            ty=motionEvent.getY();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

canvasview.java

```
enter public class canvasview extends View {
public canvasview(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(250,250,250));
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(200,200,6,paint);
}
```

}

Comment: Please start naming your classes/methods correctly according to Java standards (aMethod, AClass) - it hurts the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take. Everthing is just in a single file.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TouchCircle(this));
    }
}

class TouchCircle extends View
{
    private Paint paint;
    private float pointerX, pointerY;
    private float lastPointerX, lastPointerY;
    private float distanceX, distanceY;
    private int pointerId, pointerIndex;
    
    public TouchCircle(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        canvas.drawCircle(pointerX, pointerY, 50F, paint);
    }
    //Note :: Single touch only.
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {   
        switch(event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
                lastPointerX = event.getX();
                lastPointerY = event.getY();
                invalidate(); //This method will call onDraw().
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerId);
                pointerX = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                pointerY = event.getY(pointerIndex);
                distanceX = pointerX - lastPointerX;
                distanceY = pointerY - lastPointerY;
                invalidate();
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                //Set to the oldest touch pointer
                int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if(pointerId == this.pointerId) {
                    if(pointerIndex == 0) { pointerIndex++;
                    } else { pointerIndex = 0; }
                    this.pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                    lastPointerX = event.getX(pointerIndex) - distanceX;
                    lastPointerY = event.getY(pointerIndex) - distanceY;
                }
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```