# Draw text on canvas using a TextView X and Y positions

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing

I've an activity contains `TextView` and a `WallpaperService` where I draw some text on the canvas and display it as live wallpaper, I'm trying to draw a text on `canvas` using a `TextView` X and Y coordinates. Using the below code, I'm able to move the `TextView` around the screen.

```
    textView.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                dY = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                view.setY(event.getRawY() + dY);
                view.setX(event.getRawX() + dX);
                lastAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x = (float) event.getRawX();
                y = (float) event.getRawY();
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

Draw text based on the X and Y coordinates :

```
 Rect rect = new Rect();
 Paint timePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
 timePaint.setTextSize(DigitalClockHelper.getScaledTextSize(115));
 timePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
 timePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD));
 timePaint.getTextBounds(time, 0, time.length(), rect);
 timePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
 canvas.drawText(time, x, y, timePaint);
```

**My Issue:**

When I draw the text on the `canvas` it's drawn correctly but in a different place, just a little bit higher where it should be drawn.

**My question **

How I can draw text on `WallpaperService` exactly where the `TextView` placed in the activity.

Thank you.

Comment: For the`drawText()` methods, the y-coordinate is for the text's baseline, not its very top, as one might expect from how all the other draw methods work.

Comment: Use `getX()` and `getY()` -- relative to the view itself. Is it a single or mutiple touches? Is `time` a TextView?

Comment: @Darkman thank you for your comment is single touch, and time is a `String`

Comment: You might want to take a look at my old answer for single touch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71137325/drawing-on-android-canvas/71137718#71137718

Comment: Using `getX()` and `getY()` instead would require different logic for the listener, which is currently set on the moving target itself. Simply changing to use those methods instead would be incorrect. What they have now should be sufficient, since they're not actually using the raw coordinates for direct positioning; they're using them as reference points in delta calculations. (I've not had any coffee yet, though, so maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: I have to dig my old projects for the x and y values. `x = viewWidth / 2F;` and `y = (viewHeight / 2F) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2F);`. I believe that `viewWidth` and `viewHeight` are the width and the height of the TextView respectively.

Comment: I'm thinking they should just need to add `textView.getBaseline()` to the resulting y-coordinate. That should offset it appropriately for the `drawText()` call. Can't test anything atm, though.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong. The raw coordinates _were_ being used as the resulting (x,y), which I hadn't noticed. I'd assumed you were using the `TextView`'s (x,y). My bad. Sorry 'bout that. If you're using the `x` and `y` in `ACTION_UP` directly as the values in the draw routine, then they should be `x = view.getX();` and `y = view.getY() + view.getBaseline();` instead. In my tests, it lines up exactly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XGKM.png. The top shows my results without adding `view.getBaseline()`, which is what I'd assumed was the sole discrepancy. The bottom shows the values corrected.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me, but unfortunately, the drawn text is positioned in the completely wrong place, please look at this image : https://i.imgur.com/SRwG350.png

Comment: I think at least part of the problem is the possible difference in how the scaling is being handled in both places. I noticed that the images you last posted are scaled differently, and have differing text sizes as well, so I'm not entirely sure how you're lining things up from one place to the other. I've put together a more relevant example, and it ends up being pretty easy to line things up if you get the `Activity` to lay out just like wallpaper would: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dx7Pn_LLXwukZKaKrrwBN2oDvqyVAAEQ/view?usp=sharing. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnoeL.png.

Comment: I found this rather interesting, so here's another example, if it might help ya. This one uses a custom preview `View`, and doesn't require the `Activity` or that `View` to be the full size of the screen. It also scales the preview text size appropriately: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DymKQaiDFR_6MZal4uhiYwG57vgnkAz7/view?usp=sharing. (Sorry 'bout the Drive file still; I'm having GitHub issues.) Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0K6w.jpg.

Comment: @MikeM. Massive thanks for your help, I really appreciate it, and accept my apologies for taking from time to help me

Comment: Hey, just a heads up: `TextView` apparently has a long-standing bug where it doesn't resize correctly when changing the text size. Depending on how it's initialized, it's possible to end up with the `TextView` actually smaller than the text, clipping it abnormally, or one that's too big, allowing it to be dragged from outside the text bounds. I'm probably gonna refactor my second example to get rid of the `TextView` altogether and handle it manually. Just thought I'd let you know, in case that might be a problem for your design, too. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@MikeM.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) For helping me to fix my issue by providing an [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DymKQaiDFR_6MZal4uhiYwG57vgnkAz7/view)

However, I've ended up using the following :

```
int y = view.getY() + view.getBaseline()
```

Also, since the status bar and the navigation bar are hidden in the live wallpaper preview, I've made the activity full screen to make it similar to the live wallpaper preview.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the **raw** version of the coordinates the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getRawX(int)) say

> Returns the X coordinate of the pointer referenced by pointerIndex for this motion event. The coordinate is in the coordinate space of the device display, irrespective of system decorations and whether or not the system is in multi-window mode. If the app spans multiple screens in a multiple-screen environment, the coordinate space includes all of the spanned screens.

use the event's [getX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getX(int)) and [getY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getY(int)) instead as thes are

> Returns the X coordinate of the pointer referenced by pointerIndex for this motion event. The coordinate is in the coordinate space of the view that received this motion event.

So the these would be relative to the view `time` and would be the same coordinates as `time`'s canvas

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunately, it does not work, now, the text is placed in a different place

Comment: You don't show enough code but if the listener and canvas are of the same view and you don't have any canvas transformations like translate, scale, etc then they will be the same coordinates, the other point is the `drawtext` position might be in the corner of the drawtext depending on your paint settings.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment, I've updated my question, please read it again, I've added some explication and code